# Question on Feynman's Improved Stern-Gerlach Experiment rotated about the $z$-axis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, interferometry

I'm having trouble understand Feynman's reasoning that particles in Fig. 6-5 (b) will end in an unknown state.

[image]

Feynman reasons quote:

> Suppose that we put an apparatus in front of S which produces a pure (+x) state. (The x-axis points toward the bottom of the figure.) Such particles would be split into (+z) and (−z) beams in S, but the two beams would be recombined to give a (+x) state again at P1 —the exit of S. The same thing happens again in T. If we follow T by a third apparatus U, whose axis is in the (+x) direction and, as shown in Fig. 6-5(a), all the particles would go into the (+) beam of U. Now imagine what happens if T and U are swung around together by 90∘ to the positions shown in Fig. 6-5(b). Again, the T apparatus puts out just what it takes in, so the particles that enter U are in a (+x) state with respect to S. But U now analyzes for the (+y) state with respect to S, which is different. (By symmetry, we would now expect only one-half of the particles to get through.)

Why does T put out what it takes in, but U doesn't in the orientation of Fig. 6-5(b)? Additionally, why would only one-half of the particles get through?

Comment: I think that passage is a bit unclear and that he must be alluding to if one were to block off the minus  beam in U, in fig. a all the particles would go through, but in fig. b only half would be expected to go through

Comment: @user330563 that definitely explains a lot. Thank you!